# CLR error:8007000b

Tags: .net

when i open the IBM Information Sever Console i am getting the below error message.

CLR error:8007000b

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly programming related but refer to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/6e6b8496-c1f1-4fc9-bcc9-2129a6329804), specifically the 3 posts at the bottom. It might be helpful.